# iframe alternate to serve dynamic data on cached website

Tags: wordpress, caching, iframe

I am trying to remove the iframe from a wordpress website. The content inside the iframe is also originating from the same site. So I can modify the code of the iframe content and embed it within the WP website.

The problem is:

1) The website is cached using wordpress caching plugin "WP-Super Cache" due to the heavy traffic on the site. This is done to improve page-load speed and save band-width to re-load the static contents on the page.

2) The dynamic content is served from inside the iframe is a php script and it is not being cached.

3) This dynamic data in iframe is in the form of "live data represented on Google Charts". Update frequency 1~3 minute. Hence, the previous developer implemented the live chart using iframe along with caching plugin.

4) Now, if we remove caching, the page speed suffers. And if we load the page with caching (without iframe) then the data is updated on the charts.

Here is the link for reference:

```
http://www.niftytrader.in/bn-intra-pcr-trend/
```

Any help in finding the optimum solution would be highly appreciated.